# OpenStack :One virtual system sum of several hardware resources?

Tags: virtualization, openstack

For example i have a shared hosting server on bare metal which it's resources going to full . I don't want to upgrade the hardware to new one be cause i have several unused servers same as this one . 
Also creating new server beside this one is not an option because i have to buy new software license for new servers . right now i have "Unlimited domains license" .

Assume i have 5 same servers each one 8 cpu , 32GB Ram . is it possible to have a strong virtual system with ~40 cpu , ~160GB  and install my license on that ?

Note: I don't want clustering by that mean . i just want to install plain windows server or ubuntu server on that strong virtual system and easily extend it .

Answer (score 2):

The general buzzword you are looking for is "Virtualization for Aggregation" - Have a look here for more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualization_for_aggregation

There is no free solution out there that I know of, but have a look at ScaleMP for a commercial solution: http://www.scalemp.com/

There is also a discussion about alternatives here: [Alternatives to scalemp](https://serverfault.com/questions/187850/alternative-to-scalemp)